# Numerical Differentation for Complex Functions

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

Given a function $f(x)$, there is a way to approximate  $f'(x)$: the finite-step formula. ${\displaystyle {\frac {f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}}}$, for $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small. The smaller $\epsilon$ is, the more accurate the answer would be. However, I don't believe that carries over to $f(z)$. So, how would it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does carry over.

For complex functions, the definition of derivative is the same:

$$ f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} \ \text{(if that limit exists)}$$
except that $h$ is allowed to be complex.  But if you know $f'(z)$ exists, you are certainly allowed to take $h$ to be positive.  So $(f(z+\epsilon) - f(z))/\epsilon$ is
an approximation to $f'(z)$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!